# How many dice throws are needed in order to be 99% sure that the mean is between 3 and 4

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The problem is stated as:

> How many times do you need to roll a die to be at least ≈ 99% certain that the
> sample mean is between 3 and 4?

The aim of the problem is to use the central limit theorem.

Let $X_k$ be the k:th throw of the dice. Notice that $X_1,X_2,...$ are independent. Also, let $\hat{\mu}_n := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ be our sample mean.

We are searching for the $n$ such that $P(3\leq \hat{\mu}_n \leq 4) \geq 0.99$

We know that $E[\hat{\mu}_n] = 7/2$ since $E[X_k] = 7/2$ using linearity. Also, note that $Var(\hat{\mu}_n) = \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot n \cdot 105/36 = 105/(36n)$ by using the fact that $Var(X_k) = 105/36$ and that they're independent. Therefore, we get:

$$P(3\leq \hat{\mu}_n \leq 4) = P(\hat{\mu}_n \leq 4) - P(\hat{\mu}_n \leq 3) = $$

$$ = P(\frac{\hat{\mu}_n-7n/2}{\sqrt{105/(36n)}\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{4-7n/2}{\sqrt{105/(36n)}\sqrt{n}}) - P(\frac{\hat{\mu}_n-7n/2}{\sqrt{105/(36n)}\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{3-7n/2}{\sqrt{105/(36n)}\sqrt{n}}) = $$

$$ \approx \Phi(\frac{24-21n}{\sqrt{105}}) -\Phi(\frac{18-21n}{\sqrt{105}})$$

But testing for different n's, this converges too fast to 0. I'm wondering what went wrong in my solution. Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\operatorname{E}[\hat \mu_n] = \frac{7}{2}$$ irrespective of the sample size $n$.  Your variance calculation is correct.  Thus
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[3 \le \hat \mu_n \le 4] &= \Pr\left[\frac{3 - \operatorname{E}[\hat \mu_n]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[\hat \mu_n]}} \le \frac{\hat \mu_n - \operatorname{E}[\hat \mu_n]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[\hat \mu_n]}} \le \frac{4 - \operatorname{E}[\hat \mu_n]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[\hat \mu_n]}}\right] \\
&\approx \Pr\left[\frac{3 - \frac{7}{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{35}{12n}}} \le Z \le \frac{4 - \frac{7}{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{35}{12n}}} \right] \\
&= \Pr\left[ -\sqrt{\frac{3n}{35}} \le Z \le \sqrt{\frac{3n}{35}} \right] \\
&= 2\Phi(\sqrt{3n/35}) - 1.
\end{align}$$
Note you have mistakenly written $7n/2$, which represents the expectation of the sample *total*, rather than the sample *mean*, which is $7/2$.  Hence we require $$2\Phi(\sqrt{3n/35}) - 1 \ge 0.99,$$ or $$\sqrt{\frac{3n}{35}} \ge \Phi^{-1}(0.995) \approx 2.57583,$$ or $n \ge 77.4071$.  Since $n$ is an integer, we require $n \ge 78$ trials.

Comment: Ohhhh I see now... Thank you really for spotting that mistake for me!